# Different color for each row in a ListView, I want to drag the row and each row's background color exchange too. how to do it

Tags: java, android, listview, drag-and-drop

I set a different color for each row in a `ListView` and I want to `Drag and Drop` each row along with the corresponding background color.

the way to set different row background is showing below, now I want to drag row to change with other row and each row's background must be exchange too

```
public static class DragListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public DragListAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, 0, objects);           
        }       
        public List<String> getList(){
                   return list;
        }       
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;

                view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drag_list_item, null);

                 TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.drag_list_item_text);
                 textView.setText(getItem(position));

             switch(position){
             case 0:
                      textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray);
                  break;
             case 1:     
                      textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
                      break;
             case 2:     
                         textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Pink);
                         break;
             case 3:     
                        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Cyan);
                        break;
             case 4:     
                        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Gainsboro);
                        break;
             case 5:     
                        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Magenta);
                        break;
             case 6:     
                        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.MediumSpringGreen);
                        break;
             case 7:     
                        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.SteelBlue);
                        break;
             case 8:     
                        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Yellow);
                        break;
             case 9:     
                        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.LightSteelBlue);
                        break;

             }
                  return view;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail that what you are looking for ?Thanks

Comment: i want to drag row to change with other row and each row's background must be exchange too